# Packet loss issue

Tags: networking

My internet download speed is 8 Mbps, upload speed is 17.6 Mbps ping is 2 ms & jitter is also 2 ms. The problem is when I run the packet loss check by running this command: `ping -n 100 8.8.8.8` it gives 100% packet loss but it should be under or equals 1%. What should I do to make it under 1% ?

Answer (score 0):

Porbably ICMP (which ping uses by default, ICMP ECHO_REQUEST (type 8) to  be specific) is blocked by a firewall, therefore you have a 100% packet loss